# How to sort data with a case statement - using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a query but I want to order the data as the following:

1. status (so I have the records with status = 1 on the top and status 2 at the bottom)
2. if the records have `status = 1` then order them as the following
   a) `CASE WHEN i.assigned_to = '.USER_ID.' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`
   b) `CASE WHEN (i.approved_by > 0 OR i.approved_on IS NOT NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`
   c) `i.priority DESC`
   d) `i.created_on ASC`
3. if the records have `status = 2` then order the records by `completed_on DESC`

This is my current syntax but I can't figure out how to split the order

```
ORDER BY
  i.status ASC,
  CASE WHEN i.assigned_to = '.USER_ID.' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  CASE WHEN (i.approved_by > 0 OR i.approved_on IS NOT NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  i.priority DESC,
  i.created_on ASC
```

My query currently order all the records by
a) CASE WHEN i.assigned_to = '.USER_ID.' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
b) (CASE WHEN (i.approved_by > 0 OR i.approved_on IS NOT NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
c) i.priority DESC
d) i.created_on ASC

and I want it to order by those only if the `status = 1` otherwise order by `completed_on DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ORDER BY
  i.status ASC,
  CASE WHEN i.assigned_to = '.USER_ID.' and i.status = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  CASE WHEN (i.approved_by > 0 OR i.approved_on IS NOT NULL) and i.status = 1 
       THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  CASE WHEN i.status = 1 THEN i.priority END DESC,
  CASE WHEN i.status = 1 THEN i.created_on END ASC,
  CASE WHEN i.status = 2 THEN i.completed_on END DESC
```